# Why mongoose ignores "commentId" property in document.comments array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a some code:

```
const taskId: number = req.body.taskId;
const text: string = req.body.text;

const task = await db.tasks.findOneAndUpdate(
  { taskId },
  { $push: { comments: [{
        commentId: await db.getId(`task.${taskId}.commentId`),
        taskId,
        // @ts-ignore
        author: Number(req.session.userId),
        text,
        timestamp: Date.now()
      }] } }
).catch(e => {
  console.error(e);
  return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: "UNKNOWN_ERROR" }] });
});

if (!task) return res.json({ errors: [{ location: "query", msg: "NOT_FOUND", param: "taskId" }] });

return res.json(task);
```

But I have out (I skipped other properties):

```
{
  ...,
  comments: [{
    "timestamp": 1595833609905,
    "_id": "5f1e7d09c1e15d4c8e0b71fa",
    "taskId": 2,
    "author": 435214391,
    "text": "haha test comment"
  }]
}
```

In comment property "commentId" is undefined.. But if I use

```
console.log({
        commentId: await db.getId(`task.${taskId}.commentId`),
        taskId,
        // @ts-ignore
        author: Number(req.session.userId),
        text,
        timestamp: Date.now()
})
```

I see the "commentId" property. Why it not saves in database? (Mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

Okey, this is win. Error has been found in imports:

```
import TaskResponseSchema from './TaskResponse';
import TaskCommentSchema from './TaskResponse';
```

But okey:

```
import TaskResponseSchema from './TaskResponse';
import TaskCommentSchema from './TaskComment';
```